# android width of linearlayout the same as image

Tags: android, image, layout, width

I have my `layout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         >
             <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/id_new_big_list_item_image"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"   
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"   /> 

              <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:background="@drawable/round_corners_new_bottom" >

                  <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id_new_big_list_item_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/new_restaurant_name"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp" />



              </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I need to show image at the top (center horizontal) and below linearlayout with textview. Image can have different width, but i want to set the width of the linearlayout the same as image has. But if text is too long, the width becomes more. How can i do that? if text's width more than image width is, make 2 lines of text.

Is it possible??

here snap of my layout :

[image]

Comment: set ImageView's `layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: welcome! If you don't mind, I have also posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set ImageView's `layout_width="wrap_content"` and remove the 2nd LinearLayout enclosing the TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_new_big_list_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"   
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"   /> 

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/id_new_big_list_item_name"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="12sp"
       android:textColor="@color/new_restaurant_name"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingRight="10dp"
       android:paddingBottom="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Image should be wrap_contant and depends on it size. TextView will place in all parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/id_new_big_list_item_image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"   /> 

       <TextView
               android:background="@drawable/round_corners_new_bottom" 
               android:id="@+id/id_new_big_list_item_name"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="12sp"
               android:textColor="@color/new_restaurant_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of taking a `LinearLayout` use a `RelativeLayout`.

And set the Bounds of your `EditText` to be **Left & right** aligned to the **ImageView** Width.So that when the length of the text is exceeding the height of the EditText is incremented in Vertical than that of Horizontal.